# What is Preventing This JPG Image From Working In HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, jpeg

I have this JPG image that I am trying to use in CSS as a `background-image` for a div container. All different images I have tried work, but this one just wont render in the viewport. If I go to inspect element, it shows the thumbnail when I hover over the elements URL.

I have tried everything including:

- Putting it in an img tag and giving it a static height/width
- Converting it to png and svg'
- Compressing it
- Scraping the metadata
- Using it in a different HTML/CSS file

```js
import image from "./image.jpg";

//using React.js

<img src={image} className="image"/>//<-- doesnt work in img as src
<div className="imageBg"></div> //<-- doesnt work in div as bg
```

```css
.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.imageBg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("./image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Here's the culprit: (its just a 2000x2000 729KB .jpg mockup image edited in photoshop)

[image: broken image]

[image]

Is there something wrong with this image?

Comment: Upload the image as a raw file somewhere. Also, provide an example without the use of react, if the problem can be reproduced also without tht

Comment: @CristianTraìna I replaced my profile picture on google with it, and it worked. Ill try it without react.

Comment: "I am using React.js" — And you aren't using absolute URLs and one of your examples uses a variable not a string … so the problem is likely in how your toolchain processes the files and tries to make them available for your HTML and CSS … your toolchain *probably* uses webpack (it is really common) but you haven't shown us the configuration so we can't help you debug it.

Comment: I have just run it as both a src and a background-image using pure HTML/CSS and the image you gave hosted on imgur. It all works fine.

Comment: So the image that doesn't work is the one with `ad0` in the file name? Do you have any ad-blockers installed in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you guys dont believe me, heres the bug in action: codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-kare-212iuy?file=/src/App.js

It works fine when I open that in an incognito window, but if I open it in a regular window…

[image: Blocked by uBlock Origin shown in Developer Tools]

… the file name in your live example (although not in the code you included in the question) ends in `ad0.jpg` which is a naming convention that triggers common ad-blocking algorithms.

Don't call it that.

Moral of the story: If an image isn't loading then look at the Network tab of your browser to find out what happens when the browser tries to load it.

Comment: It was adblocker, and now I know that Ublock Origin blocks files with the name "ad" in it LMAO, its weird how it worked fine in a blank HTML document though. Maybe because I didnt run it in a web server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a high chance of the Image getting Corrupted, try doing a small edit in any editing software (photoshop, or even system default apps) and save it again and try using it!
You can also simply take a screenshot of it and try using it in your code

If that doesn't work, you can use this link `https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGYHM.jpg` in your src as a string, this is the image uploaded to Stackoverflow's drive and test it for time being! if that works as a permanent solution create an account and Try Uploading it to a Cloud Assert Provider like [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) and add it as a Link in the src

Comment: The image works just fine in your sandbox.